# try to recover views from custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made a custom cell from my storyboard, with an UIImageView and a UILabel. Each of them have a tag 100 for the imageView and 102 for UILabel.
I try to get them in my datasource method but as below, they are still nil and I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: dont use screenshots of code. Impossible to edit.

Comment: yes sorry, it was mainly for the debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewWithTag:` is a very fragile way to get a reference to views, and isn't recommended. But what I think is happening is that you need to call `viewWithTag:` on `cell.contentView` rather than the cell itself.

I'd recommend creating proper `IBOutlet`s to hold your imageview and label.

Comment: Do i need to allocate my outlets before setting their values?

Comment: @AnthonyRn No need to allocate, just connect the outlets in Interface Builder.